# subdividing edges based on a maximum length

Tags: osmnx

Is there any way in osmnx or networkx to subdivide/resample/split street edges based on a maximum length?

I'm doing shortest path routing based on addresses, but my maps often don't have enough node resolution to put a node close enough to each address.  Subdividing edges would allow me to insert more nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this OSMnx PR](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/pull/234) which includes some discussion of subdividing edges into 50 meter chunks.

In particular, you can use OSMnx's `redistribute_vertices` [function](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils.redistribute_vertices) which borrows logic from this stackoverflow [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906124/interpolating-every-x-distance-along-multiline-in-shapely).